# Does the argument value reset in python after a stack ends?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

this is a problem from Allen Downey's : Think Python ( It draws a lightning bolt like structure with branches but I can't understand how the branches are made ) , I've seen 2 solutions for it before but none of them explains how the second part works .

```
t = turtle.Turtle()


def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    angle = 50
    t.fd(length * n)
    t.lt(angle)
    draw(t, length, n - 1)
    """ The turtle draws 4 lines ( n = 4 ) of decreasing length at an angle of 50 degrees """
    t.rt(angle * 2)  # Turns the turtle to an angle of 100 degrees to match the previous turns angle ?
    draw(t, length, n - 1)  
    t.lt(angle)  # Turns the turtle back to 50 degrees 
    t.bk(length * n)  


draw(t, 10, 4)


After drawing the basic skeleton when the n value reaches 0 and the pointer returns to t.rt(angle * 2 ) does the n value reset back to 4 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not reset the value of "n".

Since "draw" is a recursive function, there are multiple "draw" and "n" until the program ends.

---

I recommend you to think about the output for each value of n from 0 to 4.

- When n = 0, nothing happens.
- When n = 1, then

  - the turtle moves forward (for "length = 10" units),
  - rotate left(50),
  - tries to draw at n=0 but nothing happens,
  - turns right(100)
  - again tries to draw at n=0 but nothing happens,
  - turns left(50) to the original angle,
  - moves back to the starting point
  - **it just made a straight line**
- When n = 2, then

  - the turtle moves forward (for 10*2 units), rotate left(50),
  - rotate left(50),
  - tries to draw at n=1, which draws a straight line at 50 degree angle(cw),
  - turns right(100)
  - again tries to draw at n=1, which draws a straight line at 50 degree angle(anti-cw),
  - turns left(50) to the original angle,
  - moves back to the starting point
  - **it just made a straight line (20 units) and a two straight lines (10 units)diverging from the first**

*And so on...*

The point is n is the same for a function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jitesh Bhai . Here's what I think is happening , please point out my mistakes : 

`1 . n = 4  - Draws a forward line of 40 magnitude 
2. t.lt(50) - Turns the turtle by 50 degrees 
3. draw(n-1) - Changes n value to 3
4. n = 3 - Draws a line of magnitude 30 at and angle of 50
( This loop draws the basic frame for the branches to be drawn on )`

At n = 0 the if statement is satisfied and the pointer returns to t.rt(100)

Now does the second draw recursion changes n from 0 to - 1 ?

Comment: Yes, after n=0, it will go back to the function with n = 1, pointer returns to t.rt(100), the second "draw" will use n =1 - 1 = 0, then again it will go back to the function with n = 1, turn left(50) and so on. Since it will follow [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Although, All those "n" are different for every function, so I can't say n changes.